# Are SMART offline data collection and offline attributes obsolete?

Tags: smartctl, smart, smartmontools

**TLDR;**

I tried to understand the difference between SMART `Offline` and `Always` attributes, and thus to understand what SMART offline data collection is, and if I should enable it on my HDDs.

`smartmontools`' [official wiki](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/test_offline) states that :

> Note that the SMART automatic offline test command is listed as Obsolete in every version of the ATA and ATA/ATAPI Specifications. (...) However it is implemented and used by many vendors.

After some extensive reading on the web, and also some tests, the conclusion I reached is:

- Nowadays SMART offline data collection is obsolete
- All data is updated in real time (e.g. `Offline` and `Always` attributes behave the same way)
- There is no need to enable "Auto Offline Data Collection" (`# smartctl --offlineauto=on /dev/sda`), nor to ever launch it manually (`# smartctl -t offline /dev/sda`).
- As for the reason all this offline stuff is still in `smartmontools`, it's probably to keep it compatible with some very old HDDs that indeed implemented real offline attributes.

Am I right ? Or do I miss something ?

---

**MORE DETAILS**

I did some tests on a HDD, which has 3 offline attributes (and has `Auto Offline Data Collection` disabled):

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sda
(...)
Offline data collection status:  (0x00)    Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
(...)
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       235 (114 97 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       13381561756
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       20472945077
(...)
```

I then wrote some data on that drive, and noted that all 3 attributes were updated in real time. Thus, they are in fact online (or `Always`) attributes, and not `Offline` ones.

I did the same test on a few other HDDs, the behavior was identical.